# Nifi ExecuteSQL fetching record in chunk

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to fetch data from mysql in batches ( `just like cursor`) using ExecuteSQL processor.  My ExecuteSQL attributes are :

```
Max Rows Per Flow File :  100
Output Batch Size : 10
```

But Processor is stuck unless it executes and fetches all the data.  I need to simulate cursor like scenario here.

Like as soon as mysql sends some data say 100 it create a flowfile from it and when 10 such flow file are created processor send down the line to process.

Answer (score 0):

As per [NiFi-1251](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1251) Jira, Starting from NiFi-1.8

- ExecuteSQL processor will **send out the chunks of flowfiles** i.e in your case once **`first 100 rows`** are fetched from Database then *ExecuteSQL* processor will ***send out the flowfile*** for further processing.

In case if you are using **`< NiFi-1.8`** version then we need to wait until all rows has been fetched from Database.

**(or)**

another workaround would be

1. Use **`GenerateTableFetch`** Processor to generate pages of rows sql select query.
2. Use **`ExecuteSql`** processor to execute the pages sql query.

***Flow:***

```
1.GenerateTableFetch //partition size 10
2.ExecuteSQL
3.other processors
```

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/138406/how-to-extract-text-from-generatetablefetcha-and-i.html) link for more details regards to GenerateTableFetch processor.